# Photoshop Graphic styles file (*.asl) to illustrator

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, style, graphic-styles

Is there any way to convert a Photoshop Style file (*.asl) to an Illustrator style file ?

Comment: For the love of everything that is sacred please _Do Not Write An Entire Question Using Title Case_.

Comment: What do you mean with 'Photoshop style to Illustrator style' ?  Raster to Vector ?

Comment: There may be equivalents in Illustrator, but without knowing which specific styles you mean, it's not really possible to provide a proper answer. Please edit your question and add more details.

Comment: I have updated my  question please help me ....

Comment: @Luciano When I read Luciano's comment it seemed to me a Brazilian talking ...

Comment: It is better to post an example image so we can understand what are you refering to. :o)

Answer (score 4):

Photoshop Layer Styles are **not** compatible with Illustrator. In addition, there is *no way* to "convert" them.

You would need to construct Illustrator styles within Illustrator.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very unclear question, so here is a pretty wild guess; you want to change raster image to vector image?

Raster image uses pixels, gets blurry/blocky when zoomed. Vector image uses math, can be zoomed infinitely.
Some images (logos, flat colors) can easily be made from raster to vector. But complex mages (photos) are very hard to convert, and you should hire an artist.

There are tools, for example https://www.vectorizer.io that can try to convert raster to vector, but results depend on the style and quality of your picture.

Comment: Sorry for confusion .. I have some Photoshop neon graphics style which I want to use in illustrator ... So is it possible ?

Comment: I have edited the description please help me someone

Comment: @asiffahim Oh like that. No, sorry those can not be converted. However, Illustrator has a style system of its own, so you can look at the ones from Photoshop and try to re-make them. Check what kind of blend modes it uses, what kind of blur size, etcetera.